# Keyword search over a collection of OWL ontologies

Tags: full-text-search, ontology, owl, triplestore

I have a collection of OWL ontologies. Each ontology is stored in a dataset of a triple store database (e.g OWLIM, Stardog, AllegroGraph ). Now I need to develop an application which supposes searching these ontologies based on keywords, i.e., given a keyword, the application should return ontologies that contains this keyword.

I have checked OWLIM-SE and Stardag, they only provide full text search over one dataset but not the whole database. I also have considered Solr(Lucene). But in this case the ontologies will be indexed twice (once by Lucene, another one by triple store database.)

Is there any other solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what you want _is_ possible with the products you mentioned. Have you tried contacting the developers to ask how to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stardog's full text indexing works over an entire database and [can be done](http://stardog.com/docs/using/#search) transparently with SPARQL which will allow you to easily access other properties of the concepts matching your search criteria in a single query.  This will get you precisely what you're describing.

For some information on administering the search indexes, and Stardog in general, check out [these docs](http://stardog.com/docs/admin/#search)